# uart buffer is not read

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, buffer, uart

I am trying to read binary data from a serial device in c on linux.
The problem is, that sometimes there are chars in the driver's internal buffer, but polling (with select(2)) returns saying the device is not ready to be read.

I have read and re-read the man of termios and all the related man and searched over the internet. I believe I set all the flags correctly (namely VTIME, VMIN) and unset ICANON.
I tried using the function "tcmakeraw", as well, but it didn't solve the problem.

Do you guys have any ideas about what should I do?

Kind regards & Thanks in advance
Yannay

Comment: Are you remembering to re-populate `readfds` before *every* call to `select()`?

Comment: What type of serial port?  (i.e. a real 16550, a 16550 clone, a USB converter, bluetooth, irda, ...)

Answer (score 1):

You should show us the code. I would start with using cfmakeraw on the serial port.
Once you have things working in raw mode, you can make modification and see how it works.
Here is a list of question or things you could check :

- after modifying the attribute, using for example cfmakeraw, do you call tcsetattr(...) to
  apply your change ?
- How do you prove there is still data in the driver receive buffer ?
- do you check your system call for errors ?
- what is the result of [stracing](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) your program ?

Edit based on your comments :
Your protocol "guarantee" .... => check your assumption ! Unchecked, *crystal clear* guarantee are a good coandidate for "impossible error"

Basically : either [select is broken](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html), or your serial driver. Reason for serial driver being broken is a hardware fifo not being full enough to trigger un interrupt, or loosing an interrupt.

Comment: 1. yes. 2. its complicated. the protocol I am using guarantees an ACK after every message. Sometimes I don't get the ack unless more data is sent from the device. I am 100% it is not the problem. 3. Of course. 4. I will try it if all fails...

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you read directly (not through C) `/dev/ttyS0` (or equiv) after you `setserial` your parameters.  Are you able to get the needed data outside of the `select()`?

Comment: The only flags which are set are: CREAD, CLOACL, CS8, NL0, CR0, TAB0, BS0, VT0, FF0. the baud rate is set correctly. VMIN=1, VTIME=0. However, the problem is not solved/ I am trying to read without the select. simply read and no byte is returned.